# Firebase Topic Messaging always return InvalidRegistration error when push notifications in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Asp.NET MVC application. In my application, I need to push notifications to Android Devices using Firebase. This is the consequence of this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416654/unable-to-push-firebase-notifications-to-multiple-devices-using-webclient-in-asp I asked.

After I searched for solutions, I realized that I should use Topic Messaging of Firebase - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging. But when I use topic messaging and push from server, it always return Error=InvalidRegistration error.

I subscribe to a topic in Android like this

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("newsTopic");
```

Then I push like this in asp.net

```
public string PushNotifications()
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization:key={0}", Utils.FirebaseServerKey)); //get from firebase
                var values = new NameValueCollection();


                values["to"] = "/topics/newsTopic";
                values["data.message"] = "This is the test FCM test message";
                var response = client.UploadValues("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", values);
                string responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseString))
                {
                    return responseString;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Something went wrong";
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I push, it returns this Error=InvalidRegistration.

### Update

I tried replacing

```
values["to"] = "/topics/newsTopic";
```

with this

```
values["condition"] = "'newsTopic' in topics";
```

It returns, Error=MissingRegistration

Comment: Given that the code is almost the same as in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416654/unable-to-push-firebase-notifications-to-multiple-devices-using-webclient-in-asp) and you get the same error message, this would be better as an [edit to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40416654/edit).

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the problem(Error=MissingRegistration) when I did not include "Content-Type=application/json" header. Can you try adding the Content-Type header?